# Function which calls a service in gRPC

Tags: c++, grpc

I have to write a function in c++ which calls shared library which is created from gRPC client which runs the gRPC client and returns the result.
Is there any samples?

Comment: gRPC [site](https://grpc.io) covers basic use-cases such as this. I encourage you to read [Quick start for C++](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/).

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks I have read the contents but the the explainations are about a stand alone program, but I dont know how can I integrate the call of service in a function in c++ ,when I call the function the service is called, but in the tutorial I have to call the service from client.cc for example by ./client command.

Comment: for instance we have main in service and client, I dont want to have main in these two classes instead I want to have one main which can I call a service from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are Some Examples I hope i would be helpful somehow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

#ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
#include "examples/protos/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"

#else
#include "helloworld.grpc.pb.h"

    
#endif
using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class GreeterClient
{
    public:
        GreeterClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel): stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}

    // Assembles the client's payload, sends it and presents the response back from the server.
    std::string SayHello(const std::string &user)
    {
        // Data we are sending to the server.
        HelloRequest request;
        request.set_name(user);

        // Container for the data we expect from the server.
        HelloReply reply;

        // Context for the client. It could be used to convey extra information to the server and/or tweak certain RPC behaviors.
        ClientContext context;

        // The actual RPC.
        Status status = stub_->SayHello(&context, request, &reply);

        // Act upon its status.
        if (status.ok())
        {
            return reply.message();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() <<
                std::endl;
            return "RPC failed";
        }
    }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub > stub_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Instantiate the client. It requires a channel, out of which the actual RPCs are created. This channel models a connection to an endpoint (in this case, localhost at port 50051). We indicate that the channel isn't authenticated (use of InsecureChannelCredentials()).
    GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
    std::string user("world");
    std::string reply = greeter.SayHello(user);
    std::cout << "Greeter received: " << reply << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**OR**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h > // for dlopen, dlsym, dlclose
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void *handle;   // handle to the library
    string(*func)(string);  // function pointer
    char *error;    // error message

    handle = dlopen("/home/user/Desktop/grpc_client/libgrpc_client.so", RTLD_NOW);  // open the library
    if (!handle)
    {
        fputs(dlerror(), stderr);   // print error message
        exit(1);
    }

    func = (string(*)(string)) dlsym(handle, "run_grpc_client");    // get the function pointer
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(error, stderr);   // print error message
        exit(1);
    }

    string result = func("hello");  // call the function
    cout << result << endl;

    dlclose(handle);    // close the library
    return 0;
}
```